# Read the corresponding image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I calculated the distance between an image A1 and different images like image1,image2,image3 and image4 based on its hierarchicalCentroid. dist_1_1{ii} contains 4 values. I want to find the minimum value present in the dist_1_1{ii}.But I shows the value 1 and also i want to show the image which gives minimum value. Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
%% demo
clc,clear all,close all
plotFlag = 1;
depth = 6;

alef1 = im2bw(imread('C1.bmp'));   %% Binary image

vec1 = hierarchicalCentroid(alef1,depth,plotFlag);
% subplot(1,3,1);
A=[];
vec2=[];
dist_1_1=[];
for ii=1:4
    A{ii} = imread(['image' num2str(ii) '.bmp']);


% subplot(1,3,2);
vec2{ii} = hierarchicalCentroid(A{ii},depth,plotFlag);

%subplot(1,3,3);
%vec3 = hierarchicalCentroid(tav,depth,plotFlag);
% vec4=hierarchicalCentroid(A,depth,plotFlag);
% vec5=hierarchicalCentroid(A,depth,plotFlag);

dist_1_1{ii} = sum((vec1 - vec2{ii}) .^ 2);

[~,I] = min(dist_1_1{ii});
figure;
subplot(1,2,1);imshow(alef1);
subplot(1,2,2);imshow(A{I});
end
```

Comment: how are your images organized? Are they in a cell array, in different folders? How do you read them? And what is the distance between 2 images? Please provide much mure details and code so we can help you better. Thanks!

Comment: Specify your question. You can use `imshow(A)` to show your image.

Comment: Sir I changed my question and I added some codes.I want the variable I have the smallest value present in the dist_1_1{ii}.But it shows the value one(1). So A{I} shows the first image present in the folder. dist_1_1{ii} have the values 1.9009,1.6763,0.3698,1.1932

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your images are named such as `image1.png`, `image2.png`,...
first, read and store the images in a cell

```
for ii=1:n
    A{ii} = imread(['image' num2str(ii) '.png']);
end
```

Then compute the similarity between the image `A1` and other images:

```
ind = computeSimilarity(A1,A);  % here you compute the similarity and
```

(of course you would need a for-loop.)

After you have stored the values in the `ind` vector:

```
ind  = [0.76,1.96,2.96];
```

Then find the index of a minimum value and choose the image accordingly

```
[~,I] = min(ind);
figure;
subplot(1,2,1);imshow(A1);
subplot(1,2,2);imshow(A{I});
```

**What should be corrected in your code:**

First of all, avoid using cell when it is not necessary and define it correctly when you using it. You cannot define a cell array like `A=[]`. You should do it like this: `A=cell(2,3)`. For instance, for storing the vector of the descriptors you do not need a cell, just store them as a matrix, as I did.

Second of all when posting your code here, remove the unnecessary parts such as commented plots and commands.

And then, try to modify your code as follows, I might made some mistake about the dimensions, but you can get the main idea.

and also remember that you do not need to check each distance inside the loop. Calculate the vectors first and then find the distances in one step, as I did.

```
depth = 6;
alef1 = im2bw(imread('C1.bmp'));   
vec1 = hierarchicalCentroid(alef1,depth,0);

A=cell(1,4);
vMatrix=zeros(4,length(vec1));

for ii=1:4
    A{1,ii} = imread(['image' num2str(ii) '.bmp']);
    vecMatrix(ii,:) = hierarchicalCentroid(A{1,ii},depth,0);
end

dist = sum((repmat(vec1,4,1) - vMatrix) .^ 2,2);
[~,I] = min(dist);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your guidance. I found out the minimum using 'MinVal=min(cell2mat(dist_1_1));' Now I want to find the corresponding image. MinVal give the minimum value 'imshow(A(MinVal))' does not give the corresponding image.How will i get it?what are changes need to be done to get this? Please help me

Comment: When using the 'min' function you can get both the minimum value and the corresponding index. `[M,I]=min(...)`, then you should use the index `I` to call the image not the minimum value 'M`.

Comment: Sir, the variable I gives only the value 3.I dont know the reason

Comment: So the image with index 3 should be the nearest then.